# Finding custom printer-specific options on *nix

Tags: unix, printing, cups

I have a printer set up using CUPS (FujiXerox Document Center 1100), it is named DC1100.

There are capabilities of the printer that are not shows as options of the printer as listed by:

```
lpoptions -l -d DC1100
```

The output is below:

> PrintoutMode/Printout Mode: Draft *Normal High Photo
>   InputSlot/Media Source: Upper Lower MultiPurpose LargeCapacity Manual *Standard
>   PageSize/Page Size: *Letter A4 C5 C6 COM10 DL Executive Legal Monarch Statement
>   PageRegion/PageRegion: Letter A4 C5 C6 COM10 DL Executive Legal Monarch Statement
>   STP_Brightness/Brightness: 0.00 0.02 0.04 [snip] 2.00
>   STP_Contrast/Contrast: 0.00 0.05 0.10 0.15 [snip] 4.00
>   STP_ColorCorrection/Color Correction: Accurate Bright Density [snip] Uncorrected
>   STP_DitherAlgorithm/Dither Algorithm: Adaptive EvenTone Fast [snip] VeryFast
>   STP_EnableDensity/Density Enable: *Disabled Enabled
>   STP_Density/Density Value: 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 [snip] 8.0
>   STP_EnableGamma/Composite Gamma Enable: *Disabled Enabled
>   STP_Gamma/Composite Gamma Value: 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.25 [snip] 4.00
>   STP_LinearContrast/Linear Contrast Adjustment: *False True
>   STP_Duplex/Double-Sided Printing: DuplexNoTumble DuplexTumble *None
>   Resolution/Rendering Resolution: *FromPrintoutMode 150x150dpi 300x300dpi 600x600dpi
>   OutputType/Output Type: *FromPrintoutMode BlackAndWhite Grayscale
>   STP_ImageType/Image Type: *FromPrintoutMode Photo Graphics LineArt None Text TextGraphics
>   STP_Resolution/Resolution: *FromPrintoutMode 150dpi 300dpi 600dpi

I am particularly looking for options for:

- "secure print" (possibly by setting a mode and setting a username)
- stapling
- hole punching

Perhaps I need a special driver/PPD file? If so, any pointers as I have no idea where to look for one. I haven't been able to find one on the official site (I've found a UNIX driver which only resulted in the above) or on sites such as http://www.openprinting.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, of all files, I had to download this one:

"PS PPD for WiPS PPD for **Windows OS**"

At least it is working as expected now :)